# Symfony3 form errors are not shown(just notNull/notBlank), the rest of them are working

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, notnull

I try to validate a symfony3 form, I use two constraints for each entity field, (NotBlank and Float). Float constraint's error message are shown correctly, for NotBlank error messages are shown just for whole form(global errors) not for  each separated filed. Also I've tried to use NotNull instead of NotBlank, this didn't help me.

Bellow I've copy/pasted snippets of code.

```js
class ParametersType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('variable_sheer_header',  NumberType::class, [
                'label' => 'parameters.variable_sheer_header',
                'error_bubbling' => true ,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'parameters.variable_sheer_header',
                    "class" => 'form-control'
                ],
            ])
            ->add('variable_sheer_hem',     NumberType::class, [
                'label' => 'parameters.variable_sheer_hem',
                'error_bubbling' => true ,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'parameters.variable_sheer_hem',
                    "class" => 'form-control'
                ],
            ])
            ->add('variable_sheer_overlap', NumberType::class, [
                'label' => 'parameters.variable_sheer_overlap',
                'error_bubbling' => true ,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'parameters.variable_sheer_overlap',
                    "class" => 'form-control'
                ],
            ])
    ...
```

```js
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument()
 */
class ParametersEmbedded
{
    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="parameters.field.not.float")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="parameters.field.not.empty")
     *
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="float")
     */
    protected $variableSheerOverlap;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="parameters.field.not.empty")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="parameters.field.not.float")
     *
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="float")
     */
    protected $variableSheerRod;
```

```js
-#index.html.haml



= form_start(form)
.settings-form
  %p.title-form= 'user.parameters'|trans
  .row
    .col-xs-4
      %h4.parameters-group-name='parameters.variable_sheer'|trans
      = form_row(form.variable_sheer_hem)
      = form_errors(form.variable_sheer_hem)
      = form_row(form.variable_sheer_overlap)
      = form_errors(form.variable_sheer_overlap)
      = form_row(form.variable_sheer_rod)
      = form_errors(form.variable_sheer_rod)
      = form_row(form.variable_sheer_header)
      = form_errors(form.variable_sheer_header)
    .col-xs-4
      %h4.parameters-group-name='parameters.other'|trans
      = form_row(form.other_hem)
      = form_errors(form.other_hem)
      = form_row(form.other_overlap)
      = form_errors(form.other_overlap)
      = form_row(form.other_rod)
      = form_errors(form.other_rod)
      = form_row(form.other_header)
      = form_errors(form.other_header)
    .col-xs-4
      %h4.parameters-group-name='parameters.shade'|trans
      = form_row(form.shade_add_hem_length)
      = form_errors(form.shade_add_hem_length)
      = form_row(form.shade_add_hem_width)
      = form_errors(form.shade_add_hem_width)
= form_row(form.submit)ubmit)
= form_end(form)
```

```js
// Controller


public function profileParametersAction(Request $request)
{
     $form = $this->createForm(ParametersType::class);
     $form->handleRequest($request);
  
     if ($form->isValid()) {
         $this->getUser()->setParameters($form->getData());
         $this->getDM()->flush();
         $this->addFlash('success', 'user.profile.parameters.changed');
     }

     return $this->render('AppBundle:Profile:parameters.html.haml', [
       'form' => $form->createView()
     ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You suppose to use required as true attribute to be passed in form.

Check here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required